# Как сделать проверку определенной роли у пользователя и если ее нету выдать сообщение в discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

[image: Пример команды]

Как сделать проверку определенной роли у пользователя и если ее нету выдать сообщение в discord.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@commands.command()
async def ping(self, ctx):
    if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='role_id') not in ctx.author.roles:
        return await ctx.send('You must have a role `RoleName`')
```